# Equation For a CNOT Gate Matrix, that works on multiple qubits

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, quantum-mechanics

So Say I have 3 qubits, $\lvert000\rangle$, And I want to apply a Pauli-X Gate to the second qubit.

I know that I can create the matrix that will act on those qubits, using this equation:
$$
X_{2,3} = Id \otimes X \otimes Id
$$
Where Id is a 2x2 identity matrix.

---

How would I do something similar to that with a CNOT Gate? (A General Equation for creating that would be great)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when we write the matrix of a transformation, we take our basis to be in lexicographical order.  In particular, our basis will be in the order
$$
\{|000\rangle, |001\rangle,|010\rangle, \dots\}
$$
With that in mind: to compute the overall matrix of this transformation, we use the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  In particular: 
$$
I \otimes X \otimes I = I \otimes\left[ \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \otimes \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\right] =
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} \otimes 
\pmatrix{
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0}=\\
\pmatrix{
0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0}
$$
That should help you with the CNOT as well.

Comment: **Note:** The Kronecker product is associative, so we didn't have to use this particular order.